# csv class writer : a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, csv, design-patterns

For a personal project I'm trying to upgrade the **paterns** package to Python 3. 
Actually I'm running the test:db.py,  but I'm stuck with the following error in the **'__init__.py'** file, on a csv class:

This is the code snippet od the **save()** function:
there, we dfine **s** as a **BytesIO()** stream, so the function is asked to stream bytes to a *self* csv file.
The error comes from the line:

```
w.writerows([[csv_header_encode(name, type) for name, type in self.fields]])

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' ( below, also the code for this function)
```

it's supposed that csv_header_encode to deliver bytes, and I checked this and it does, but somehow, in its conversion to list it changes to 'str'.
And if I change the **s** encoding to StringsIO then the complaining comes from

```
 f.write(BOM_UTF8)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

```
def save(self, path, separator=",", encoder=lambda v: v, headers=False, password=None, **kwargs):
    """ Exports the table to a unicode text file at the given path.
        Rows in the file are separated with a newline.
        Columns in a row are separated with the given separator (by default, comma).
        For data types other than string, int, float, bool or None, a custom string encoder can be given.
    """
    # Optional parameters include all arguments for csv.writer(), see:
    # http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer
    kwargs.setdefault("delimiter", separator)
    kwargs.setdefault("quoting", csvlib.QUOTE_ALL)
    # csv.writer will handle str, int, float and bool:
    s = BytesIO()
    w = csvlib.writer(s,  **kwargs)
    if headers and self.fields is not None:
        w.writerows([[csv_header_encode(name, type) for name, type in self.fields]])
    w.writerows([[encode_utf8(encoder(v)) for v in row] for row in self])
    s = s.getvalue()
    s = s.strip()
    s = re.sub("([^\"]|^)\"None\"", "\\1None", s)
    s = (s if not password else encrypt_string(s, password)).encode('latin-1')
    f = open(path, "wt")
    f.write(BOM_UTF8)
    f.write(s)
    f.close()

def csv_header_encode(field, type=STRING):
    # csv_header_encode("age", INTEGER) => "age (INTEGER)".
    t = re.sub(r"^varchar\(.*?\)", "string", (type or ""))
    t = t and " (%s)" % t or ""
    return "%s%s" % (encode_utf8(field or ""), t.upper())
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of why you need the `re.sub("([^\"]|^)\"None\"", "\\1None", s)` replacement? This looks likely to break your CSV output for quoted values.

Comment: Ah, you are trying to *unquote* `None` strings? A proper CSV reader will *remove* the quotes again anyway, why the bother? You probably should not use `csv.QUOTE_ALL`, and just leave quoting to the writer.

Comment: This is original code. As I said, I was just trying to upgrade it with minimal mods.

Answer (score 3):

You may be trying to write to a `BytesIO` object, but `csv.writer()` deals in *strings* only. From the [`csv` writer objects documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects):

> A row must be an iterable of **strings or numbers**

Emphasis mine. [`csv.writer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) also requires a *text* file to write to; the object produces strings:

> [...] converting the user’s data into **delimited strings** on the given file-like object.

Either use an [`io.StringIO` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) instead, or wrap the `BytesIO` object in an [`io.TextIOWrapper` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) to handle encoding for you. Either way, you'll need to pass in Unicode text to `csv.writer()`.

Because you are later on treating the `s.getvalue()` data as *strings* again (using regular expressions defined as strings, and using encoding to Latin-1), you probably want to write to text file (so `StringIO`).

That `f.write(BOM_UTF8)` fails is a *separate issue*. `f` was opened in text mode (`'wt'`) so expects strings, not `bytes`. If you want to write 
 text to a file encoded as UTF-8 with an UTF-8 BOM at the start you can use the `utf-8-sig` encoding when opening the file:

```
open(path, 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Generally, you appear to be mixing bytes and strings in all the wrong ways. Leave text *as text* for as long as possible, and only encode at the last possible moment. Here that moment would be when writing to the file at location `path`, and you can leave the encoding entirely to the file object.

Comment: Right. As I said, changing to **StringIO** solves the first error and raises the second. I changed the open method as you sugested{ f = open(path, "w",  encoding='utf-8-sig') } but then it comes the error: { write() argument must be str, not bytes}

Comment: @FSRubyc: which is why we ask people to create a [MCVE] of a problem, and ask separate questions about separate issues.

Comment: @FSRubyc: yes, as I state in my answer, *keep everything as text*, not bytes.

Comment: @FSRubyc: also, why are you attempting to encode something as Latin-1 bytes but prepend it with a UTF-8 BOM? Pick an encoding and stick to it. Preferably leave it to the file object to handle encoding.

Comment: I pick a package in Python 2.7 (https://github.com/clips/pattern) and I'm trying to make the minimum changes on it to make it Python 3 compatible.

Comment: @FSRubyc: ah, oh dear. That code is not very well written and has multiple issues even in the Python 2 implementation. I'm not sure that's really worth your time, especially if you are not well versed in Python yet.

Comment: The encoding to 'latin-1' was a mod I did to test the problem, but I already took it out .

Comment: Thanks Martijin for your time. Well, somtimes you win and sometimes you learn.